# Laravel Eloquent retrieve the first element and also keep the query result intact?

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent

Please have a look at the following code:

```
$msgs = Message::where(function($query) use ($start,$end){

    $query->whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $end));

})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

$first = $msgs->first()->created_at;
$ids = $msgs->lists('id');
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the latest date of the query result set and get all the ids from the result at the same time. But the code doesn't work because the $msgs was changed by the $msgs->first() function. I'm wondering if there is a way to let me get the first element of the query result without affecting the whole result set? Thanks

Comment: I tried:
            foreach($msgs as $message)
            {
                $first = $message;
                break;
            }               

But it seems it did not go into the foreach at all.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$first = $msgs->first(); // this does ->take(1) under the hood
```

Now your builder has `limit = 1` clause.

So basically you need this:

```
// also you can use pluck:
$first = $msgs->pluck('created_at'); // returns first row`s single field
//then:
$ids = $msgs->take(9999)->lists('id'); // some high value depending on your data
```

Your solution is not the best, as it loads all the rows and creates objects of them, while all you need is list of ids.

You can also use `first()` method of the Collection to fetch its first item, instead of that foreach loop:

```
$messages = $msgs->get();
$first = $msgs->first()->created_at;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
        $msgs = Message::whereBetween('created_at', array($start, $end))                    
                            ->whereIn('advertiser_id', $array)            
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

        $messages = $msgs->get();
        foreach($messages as $message)
        {
            $first = $message->created_at;
            break;
        }
```

Surprisingly easy. But I don't know if it's an efficient way or not.

Comment: Know this post is old but why don't you just test if you result is not empty then retrieve the created_at value of the first element of the array like this:
$first = $messages[0]->created_at.